# MVC with Entity Framework - Why data from database cannot be displayed in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first

I'm creating an asp.net web API page using entity framework. I think the connection to database is not a problem because when i run my program, in my View page, the DisplayNameFor actually successfully displays the database column name, but it fails to display the data rows through the DisplayFor. How can i fix this problem? Is there anything wrong with my coding?

This is my Controller page.

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
        Using db As DbContext1 = New DbContext1()
            Dim appointment = db.appointment.Include(Function(d) d.User).Include(Function(d) d.patient).Include(Function(d) d.surgery_booking)               
            Return View(appointment.ToList())
        End Using
End Function
```

This is my database code in web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DbContext1" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-4VUJKLS\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=----;Password=----;Integrated Security=SSPI"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: `DisplayNameFor()` reads the models metadata and can work even if the collection is empty (you also have a `@` in `@<tr>` - is that a typo?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ohh...so this means my data collection is empty..? Does the problem have to do with my coding or is there something wrong with my database migration process? Because i'm using a Code-First concept with an existing database. I'm not sure myself about @<tr>, i'm new to asp.net. When i chose to create the controller, i chose controller with views, and if i'm not mistaken, i didn't change anything in the view page. I thought the syntax is originally that way

Comment: It should be just `<tr>`. You need to debug your code - does your query return any records?

Comment: @StephenMuecke when i removed the @, all the below lines of code are underlined red saying: "Attributes cannot be applied to local variables"

Comment: @StephenMuecke i tried debugging, and the compilation error is: "BC32035: Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement."  I searched for it. I tried putting the _ thing at the end of vb.net syntax, but that didn't work either. What should i do?

Comment: Been  long time since I used VB, but maybe that is required. In any case, you need to check if you query is returning any data.

Comment: @StephenMuecke How can i check for that?

Comment: Just put a break-point on the `Return View(appointment.ToList())` line of code and check that `appointments` contains items

Comment: @Nurul there is nothing wrong with that code. In your Index function create a hardcoded model and pass that to the view. It will work. Then figure out what is wrong with the code which is retrieving from database.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've put the break-point and debug the program. In the breakpoints window, i see the Controller filename, line number and character number. Condition: no condition. Hit Count: break always. Data: [blank]. Does this data refer to the data collection you mentioned? Does this mean that data is not retrieved at all?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Just to be sure, what you meant by hard-coded model, is it something like this? Dim model = New appointment() model.name = "alan" model.updatedby = "me" ..? I tried doing this and presenting it to the view; it displays just fine.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on dim appointments, and you step to the next line, is there anything in that variable?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Sorry but which one is it? I tried 'step into' and when i checked at Breakpoints window, under Data column, nothing there. I tried step into for the second time, and it alerted that the action is directed to 'Step over'. And now, it's pointing at dbcontext class, at OnModelCreating sub/method.

Comment: this line:  Dim appointment = db.appointment.Include(Function(d) d.User).Include(Function(d) d.patient).Include(Function(d) d.surgery_booking)

Comment: @CodingYoshi i already did a breakpoint at that line. Do i have to 'step into' or 'step over' that line?

Comment: Go to the next line and then check if appointment has anything. I have to leave unfortunately. But if you check and appointment has nothing, then you should include your database first code (i mentioned this to you earlier today) so we can what your model design looks like. All that html code you have should not be in the question because it has no issue.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Where do i check for that?

Comment: If you did code first development, then you should have written it. If you did database first then it will be in a file ending with .edmx. If you dont know what code first and database first is, then google for EF code first and database first.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Could you kindly give me a hint on which part is that?

Comment: @CodingYoshi from most tutorials i've read through, it seems like they seed data to initialize their database..but do i have to do that? because i already have an existing DB with data..